# PyCharm Failing to Properly Create a Django Project

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am an experienced Java developer looking to get experience in Django and Python in general. I decided to start with the [official Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/) but I am running into problems within the first few steps.

1. I create a new Django project with the wizard:

[image]

2. Continuing with the wizard, I make sure `Enable Django admin` is checked:

[image]

3. The following directory structure is created:

[image]

4. When I open up localhost:8000 I get the following error screen:

[image]

That error message appears despite `INSTALLED_APPS` being set to the following in `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'FirstDjangoProjects.polls',
)
```

I haven't changed anything, and the official tutorial suggests that I should just be able to launch this project. So what gives?

Comment: I don't see any obvious problem in the info you've shared, but i did want to suggest skipping the project creation wizard. it's very simple to set up a django project from the command line, and then you can do it inside of a virtualenv to keep your environment clean. You can still open the project in pycharm after doing that, just set the project python interpreter to the one in the virtualenv. A quick search turned up this: http://www.nerdydork.com/django-dev-environment-virtualenv-pip-git-pycharm.html

Comment: It seems to me you're doing too many things at once.  Learn python by using django, and skip learning a Python IDE for now.  Django is quite a large framework to begin with...  IMHO you should start out with something even more basic, unless you know for sure django is what you want.

Comment: Have you followed these steps: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial02/#activate-the-admin-site? I wouldn't rely on PyCharm to create the project for you - you'd better follow the tutorial as you'll learn a lot along the way.

Comment: Never use PyCharm for project start, get familiar with the django console because you'll be sitting way more in it than you might think.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you edit urls.py to enable admin and run syncdb first before attempting to login to the admin.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this out, and PyCharm misses out on one step during the project creation - namely setting up the DB (The admin app config is all created properly for me).

When you've created the project (as you described), open `settings.py` and complete the **DATABASES** entry.  For a simple project, that means fleshing out the sqlite3 settings, eg, for windows:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
        'NAME': 'c:/temp/db.blah',        
        'USER': '', 
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Save, and run *syncdb*.  In PyCharm, either hit **Ctrl-Alt-R** or go to **Tools -> Run manage.py Task...** and select/type *syncdb*.

Since the DB is new, you'll be prompted for the standard admin django account creation, etc.  Restart the app in PyCharm (**shift-F10**), and your admin console should be available at

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin`

Seems to me JetBrains have a bit of work to do with their Django Project creation wizard.

Answer (score 0):

I think the tutorial doesn't assume you'll activate the admin whereas you've told PyCharm to create it according to the screenshot at the top, hence you just stepped outside the tutorial's scenario in that. But if you connect to the database as suggested, it should work nonetheless. Of course you'll get the admin login screen rather than the tutorial's anticipated “Welcome to Django” screen on that url, since you activated the admin, but you can consider it 'working' for the sake of a 'first django application'.

I don't think there's any implication here about PyCharm's project creation performance. Apparently you've just stepped outside the django tutorial flow. I'd also expect (although I haven't tried) the tutorial to work combined with PyCharm, if you keep 'Enable Django admin' not-ticked on that PyCharm wizard.

(Django 1.5.1 but probably other versions as well)